# How to post Photo Blog to tumblr with the "tumblr.js" NodeJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, tumblr

I'm using the tumblr.js node module for the Tumblr API, and have looked through their docs but can't figure out what is suppose to be in "options" when I blog something. All I've done thus far with this module is fetched my tumblr followers. My concerns for posting are as follow:

- How to specify tags.
- How to upload the photo from a local file ( or web address if that's all I can do. )
- How to specify the caption.
- How to specify the title.

Reference Code:

```
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');

var client= tumblr.createClient({

    consumer_key: '*',
    consumer_secret: '*',
    token: '*',
    token_secret: '*'

});

client.photo("xymonsinclair", options, callback);
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In "options" you may set an object containing the properties for that photo post. The parameters available are listed here http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#pphoto-posts.

Example:

```
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');

var client= tumblr.createClient({

    consumer_key: '*',
    consumer_secret: '*',
    token: '*',
    token_secret: '*'

});

// todo: set up your options
var options = {
    caption: '',
    link: '',
    source: '',
    data: []
};

client.photo("xymonsinclair", options, callback);
```

Comment: I would love to know how this works, I tried without any luck so far... Can you fill the options for a working example?

Comment: You must be aware that required fields are either "source" or "data" (array of "sources"), and "source" should be a string of URL-encoded binary content. In short, you have to read file using fs module and encode following chars , / ? : @ & = + $ # then you should be able to upload. More info: stackoverflow.com/questions/11435851/

Comment: @Roberto14 This might be a dumb question, but how do you set the costumer key and costumer secret key? I guess it is totally wrong to do it on client side, everyone can see it. Or I totally miss the point, and the Tumblr API should never be used on client side (for submitting photos, posts)?

Comment: @godzsa that's a good question, actually. In this case, we are using a nodejs webserver in which the client secrets are safe and hidden from the client code. In browser-based webapps, must go for a different authorization approach.